# Did Prophet (PBUH) never laugh after revelation of verses 59-60 of Surat An-Najm?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, authenticity, surat-an-najm

There is a riwayah which shows Prophet (PBUH) never laugh after revelation of verses 59-60 of Surat An-Najm till his death(AL-KASHAF 'AN HAQA'IQ AL-TANZIL of  Mahmud al-Zamakhshari,volume 4,page 430)

Is it authentic? Could Prophet (PBUH) who was known to be good-tempered,never laugh?

Comment: Why would you think there would be? This question shows absolutely no research effort.

Comment: @goldPseudo,I edited the question.would you please reopen it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the revelation of the Surat An-Najm, the Prophet (pbuh) never laughed extensively, however he used to smile all the time.

> I never saw Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) laugh to such an extent that I could see his uvula-whereas he used to smile only
>
> -[Muslim Book 9 Hadith 17](http://sunnah.com/muslim/9/17)

Comment: Al Bosiry said: سَـيِّـدٌ ضِـحْـكُهُ التـبَسُّمُ
*
وَالمَشْيُ الهُوَيْنا ونوْمُهُ الإغْفاءُ A lord who's laughter is a smile ...

Comment: there are more hadiths about smile: https://aboutislam.net/shariah/hadith/hadith-collections/5-hadiths-about-smiling/ . this is 1st result googling "islam smile hadith" (without quotes).