# Is the hadith "I did not see anyone walk faster than [Prophet Muhammad], as if the earth folded for him" authentic?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, authenticity, behavior

From [Shama'il Muhammadiyah, Book 18, Hadith 116](https://sunnah.com/urn/1801160), we have:

> Hazrat Abu Hurairah radiyallahu anhu says, "I did not see anyone more handsome as Rasoolullah sallallahu alaihe wasallam. It was as if the brightness of the sun had shone from his auspicious face. **I did not see anyone walk faster than him, as if the earth folded for him.** A few moments ago he would be here, and then there. We found it difficult to keep pace when we walked with him, and he walked at his normal pace.

It is not assigned a grade at sunnah.com.

It reminds me of [my earlier question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33406/17163) which asks about [Qur'an 31:17-19](https://quran.com/31/17-19):

> O my son, establish prayer, enjoin what is right, forbid what is wrong, and be patient over what befalls you. Indeed, [all] that is of the matters [requiring] determination.  And do not turn your cheek [in contempt] toward people and do not walk through the earth exultantly. Indeed, Allah does not like everyone self-deluded and boastful.  **And be moderate in your pace** and lower your voice; indeed, the most disagreeable of sounds is the voice of donkeys."

This makes me suspicious of its authenticity.

**Question**: Is this hadith authentic?

Comment: The given link is also of same Hadith in another Book, Sunan At Tirmazi. https://sunnah.com/urn/635190
It says that this Hadith is "Ghareeb".

Comment: And you can find the definition of "Ghareeb" Hadith in this Link
https://islamqa.info/en/126978
"Ghareeb" Hadith is also called "Ahaad".

Comment: @geekFromPeshawar the definition of at-Tirmidhi isn't the same as most scholars now use!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hadith appears not only in at-Tirmdihi's [shamaa'il](https://sunnah.com/urn/1901230) الشمائل المحمدية, but also in his [Jami'](https://sunnah.com/urn/735190) (same narrator chain), Imam Ahmad's Musnad (same narrator chain), ibn Saa'd (? author of at-Tabaqaat) and ibn Hebbans sahih (with a different narrator chain which has in it Abdullah ibn Wahb and is considered as sane by al-Alabani) according to Mubarakpuri in his [Tohfat al-Ahodhi](https://hadithportal.com/index.php?show=hadith&h_id=3739&uid=0&sharh=21662&book=38&bab_id=2190) تحفة الأحوذي.

Note that the version of Jami' at-Tirmidhi has been qualified as sahih!
Gharib (means in Arabic strange) in the terminology of at-Tirmdihi may have different meanings: like it is an ahaad, it is a hadith which in his wording contradicts more sahih narrations etc.

Based on the assumption that the hadith is rather authentic (in worst case Hassan li ghayrih = Hassan because of other supporting narrations) scholars have commented on it!

Commenting the part:

> And I have not seen anyone quicker in his walking than the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). It was as if the earth was made easy for him.

Al Mubarakpuri says :

> ( وَمَا رَأَيْتُ أَحَدًا أَسْرَعَ فِي مِشْيَتِهِ مِنْ رَسُولِ اللهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم )
> And I have not seen anyone quicker in his walking than the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ).
>
> (*My own translation, take it with the necessary care!*) - - -
>
> أي مع تحقق [الوقار](http://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1/) و[السكون](http://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%83%D9%88%D9%86/) ورعاية الاقتصاد ممتثلا قوله تعالى واقصد في مشيك
> this nevertheless means by fulfilling the necessary calmness (dignity), reposefulness, and with the necessary modesty in his pace following Allah's order "[Be moderate in your pace](http://legacy.quran.com/31/19)"
>
> ( كَأَنَّمَا الأَرْضُ تُطْوَى لَهُ )
> as if the earth folded for him.
>
> (*My own translation, take it with the necessary care!*) - - -
>
> بصيغة المجهول أي تزوى وتجمع على طريق خرق العادة تهوينا عليه وتسهيلا لأمره
> the expression was made in passive voice and means in a extraordinary (abnormal sounds to me a bit negative) manner to make it easier for him to do what he is about to do

[Mulla 'Ali al-Qari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_al-Qari) in his [commentary of the shamaa'il](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=117&ID=37&idfrom=236&idto=244&bookid=117&startno=1) جمع الوسائل في شرح الشمائل added a few points (I'll  not quote the full text nor translate every detail) which are:

- the part of the hadith refers to the way of his walk (or his pace).
- the speed of the walk was for him (the Prophet()) a very calm and slow and not in any means fast, so that it seems as if it has no dignity or calmness, so it doesn't contradict to verse (25:63) nor to (31:19).
- his () speed is due to his () strength (which is considered as complete).
- To sum up the meaning of the hadith and put things together: even if the Prophet() apparently seemed to walk fast compared to the sahaba () one couldn't see any trace of fatigue, strive or rashness in his face or appearance!

**Other narrations on the pace of the Prophet ()**

In fact at-Tirmidhi quoted in both his shamaa'il and his Jami' ahadith which clearly go ahead with the meaning of (31:19) and (25:63) which describe the pace of the Prophet () the most common statement is most on the authority of 'Ali ibn Abi Talib():

> When Rasulullah (Sallallahu alaihe wasallam) walked, it appeared that he was descending from a high place
> (ash-Shamaa'il al-Mohammadiyah [1](https://sunnah.com/urn/1900050), [2](https://sunnah.com/urn/1900080), [3](https://sunnah.com/urn/1901250), [4](https://sunnah.com/urn/1900070), [5](https://sunnah.com/urn/1901240),  Jami' [1](https://sunnah.com/urn/735060) and [2](https://sunnah.com/urn/735080))

Therefore [Imam al-Busiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Busiri) described the Prophet () in his peom the hamziyah as follows:

> سَيِّدٌ ضِحْكُهُ التَّبَسُّمُ والْمَشْـ = ـيُ الْهُوَيْنَا وَنَوْمُهُ الإِغْفَاءُ

I've added links to references for each "new" statement:

> a Lord who's [laughter is smiling](http://sunnah.com/muslim/9/17) and his pace is ease (shyly) and his [sleep is not deep](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/78)

See also [Did Prophet (PBUH) never laugh after revelation of verses 59-60 of Surat An-Najm?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25202/did-prophet-pbuh-never-laugh-after-revelation-of-verses-59-60-of-surat-an-najm)

This [Arabic thread](http://majles.alukah.net/t39765/) shows even more sources and narrator chains. Here the chain with Roshdeen ibn Sa'ad رشدين بن سعد is considered as weak, so maybe ibn Sa'ad to which al-Mubrakapuri refers to isn't the author of at-Tabaqaat!